# mixed integer programming with non-convex quadratic constraint

Tags: cplex

I am trying to implement a MIP with quadratic constraints. Unfortunately,  the Q in my quadratic constraint
a*x + x *Q *x <= rhs
is negative-definite. You can think of x = [x1, x2], and my Q = [-1,1;1,-1].
As anticipated, cplex reports error.  My questions are:
1. Is there any trick to revise the coding so that cplex can handle?
2. If not, is anybody aware of any other software that can handle this?

Much thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of tricks to making these types of problems convex or even linear, but nothing that will work in all cases.  You need to be more specific about your specific problem.

Comment: I have a indicator constraint. y (binary)=1 only if (x1-x2)^2+ 2*x1+3*x2 > c (x1, x2 continuous, c constant). If I use the "big M" trick, the quadratic constraint is  y <= 1 + ((x1-x2)^2+ 2*x1+3*x2-c)/M. However, this is not a convex constraint. Do you know any trick to make this convex?

Comment: For on thing, you don't need a bigM.  The constraint can be written (x1-x2)^2 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 >= c y.  It's still non-convex though and you need to come up with more restrictions on your variables to put it into cplex.